# Canvas width percent in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that I have in html that is supposed to be 25% of the page. I made a variable named width in javascript, and put it's value as 25%. When I make a context.clearRect(); with the width variable as the width parameter, it doesn't fix it what I was trying to do (which I have done tons of times) which is when the player rectangle moves, the clearRect keeps the background circulating so the rectangle isn't drawing (leaving a mark). 
Here is my width variable:

```
var width = 25%;
```

Here is my clearRect();

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

**Edit:** I guess I will also post my whole entire code, to be easier.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #222222;
    }
    canvas {
        background-color: #000000;
        width: 25%;
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var keys = [];

    var speed = 4;

    var width = 25%;
    var height = 400;

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        delete keys[e.keyCode];
    }, false);

    var player = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 30,
        height: 30
    };

    function game() {
        update();
        render();
    }

    function update() {
        if (keys[40]) player.y++ * speed;
        if (keys[38]) player.y-- * speed;
        if (keys[37]) player.x-- * speed;
        if (keys[39]) player.x++ * speed;
    }

    function render() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, (canvas.width * 0.25)), height);

        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        game();
    }, 1000/30);

</script>
```

Comment: What language/syntax is `var width = 25%;`?

Comment: I know how to do it now, but back then I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, (canvas.width * 0.25), height);
```

---

Try this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background-color: #222222;
      }
      canvas {
        background-color: #000000;
        width: 25%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var keys = [];

      var speed = 4;

      // var width = 25%;
      var height = 400;

      window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
      }, false);

      window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        delete keys[e.keyCode];
      }, false);

      var player = {
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        width: 30,
        height: 30
      };

      function game() {
        update();
        render();
      }

      function update() {
        if (keys[40]) player.y++ * speed;
        if (keys[38]) player.y-- * speed;
        if (keys[37]) player.x-- * speed;
        if (keys[39]) player.x++ * speed;
      }

      function render() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, (canvas.width * 0.25), height);

        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
      }

      setInterval(function() {
        game();
      }, 1000/30);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to replace all the `25%` to `0.25`.

Comment: @seanmelately Check this!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you actually wanted to ask yet your code has two syntax errors - thus it does not execute correctly:

```
var keys = [];
var speed = 4;
//var width = 25%; //This is no valid assignment and the value is not used..
var height = 400;
```

and

```
function render() {
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, (canvas.width * 0.25)), height); //One bracket too much, can skip both tho..
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width * 0.25, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your canvas in a container, and set up the container the way you want, then you make your canvas 100% of the containers properties using

```
clientHeight
```

and

```
clientWidth
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/53n2s0s9/